# htaccess help needed for https site

Tags: .htaccess, https

So I am stuck

I have a redirect for port 80 traffic to redirect to https version of the site. so all the site is on https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

All pages redirect to correct version on https.

NOW I want to change domain to dom-ain.com but I am stuck on how to redirect to this new https domain possibly non https at first.

I have back links on the web to the non https version and https version of domain.com

What should the htaccess code be if I want the site to redirect to the new domain now and I plan to keep it an exact replica in structure and content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.dom-ain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Before the new domain is https, uses:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://www.dom-ain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming if I don't use https on new domain I simply switch out https with http?   

Also, would someone clicking on an old https link to old domain get redirected to the new domain using the code you provided?   What does https} off do?

Comment: Yes, I add that in my answer. `RewriteCond %{HTTPS}` tests whether the domain is https or not.